# A thought experiment related to the age of the universe

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, astronomy, universe, cosmological-inflation

Okay, 
So, this thought experiment starts with the movie, Interstellar. In which humans went through a wormhole to a system consisting of a Black Hole. They landed on a planet (I don't remember its name) with an hour equivalent to 7 earth years. 
Now, here is my question: - 
Suppose, a scientist on that planet measures the age of the universe. Then what would be the age measured by him? Would it be 13.8 billion years or something else?

Note: - The scientist is completely unaware of the age of unvierse measured from earth.

Comment: When does he measure it?

Comment: Right now, i.e. when this question is posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The observer is subject to gravitational time dilation by a factor of about 61320. They will see a blue-shifted universe, with all the wavelengths shifted by this factor looking much younger than we see it (they will still see galaxies etc, which seem to have developed fairly fast). When they do their cosmological observations and model the past expansion of the universe they end up with an age of about 224,559 years! Except that those years are planet-years. Translate it to years as measured in non-dilated flat space and you get 13.8 billion years. It is the same universe, just different time yardsticks.

Comment: How did you calculate this exact figure of age and time dilation factor of about 224559years and 61320 respectively?

Comment: @DHRUVPATEL - If 1 hour is 7 years, the ratio of time flow is (years)*(days/year)*(hours/day)=7*365*24 = 61320. And 13.77 billion flat-space years/61320 is about 224,559 planet-years.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear.